# Space generated by Gaussian functions

Tags: functional-analysis, gaussian-integral

Let A be the space generated by all Gaussians functions
$$f_{m, \sigma}(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
where $m , \sigma \in \mathbb{R}$. Let B be the space of all continuous function of $x$ on $\mathbb{R}$ that converges to zero as $x$ tends to infinity.
I'm wondering if A is dense in B by norm $\|\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: It seems to me that the *subspace* generated by the Gaussians is even a *subalgebra* of $B$. Then you could use a suitable version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: The locally compact version seems to fit this case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Locally_compact_version